# Accessing parts of splitted string in scala

Tags: scala

I am working on a scala application. I have a string as follows:

```
val str = abc,def,xyz
```

I want to split this string and access splitted parts separately like abc , def and xyx. My code is as follows

```
val splittedString = str.split(',')
```

to access each part of this splitted string I am trying something like this `splittedString._1, splittedString._2, splittedString._3`. But intellij is giving me error stating "`cannot resolve symbol _1`" and same error for part 2 and 3 as well. How can I access each element of splitted string?

Comment: `split` returns an `Array` not a `Tuple3 `.

Comment: ok.  But  is there is any way I can achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `split` is defined over `String`s to return an `Array[String]`.

What you can do is access by (zero-based) index, `splittedString(0)` being the first item.

Alternatively, *if you know the length of resulting array you want to obtain*, you can convert it to a tuple and access with the accessor methods you were referring to:

```
val tuple =
  str.split(",") match {
    case Array(a, b, c) => (a, b, c)
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
  }
```

`tuple._1` will now contain `abc` in your example.

Comment: when I print splittedString(0) it prints  separate characters as x,y,z a,b,c

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what you're doing, you can see it working here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/4hpYn7BlQp2dqmhac32b0A/4